# C about PUTCHAR

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>

  void reverse( const char * const sPtr );

   int main ( void ) {

     char sentence[ 80 ];
     fgets( sentence, 80, stdin);

     reverse (sentence);
     return 0; 
  }

   void reverse( const char * const sPtr ){

     if (sPtr[0] == '\0' )
       return;
     else {
        reverse( &sPtr[1] );
        putchar (sPtr [0] );
     }
```

I'm confused in generally about how the reverse function is working? I do not see how the Pointer is being incremented to point the next charcter, and I don't know if I understand exactly what putchar does. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `&sPtr[1]` is the next character.  The function is called recursively until the end of the string.  `putchar` outputs a single character to stdout.

Comment: Why is it the next charcter? I do not how sPtr[1] is changing.

Comment: Every call has an ever shortening version of the string.  First call has a pointer to the first character.  Second call points to `&sPtr[1]` which means "pointer to the second character" (C arrays are zero based). The function keeps calling itself until it sees '\0' which is the C string terminator...  I hope you get the idea.  sPtr is different in every call (it's "passed by value").

Comment: does putchar disolve the 0 element?

Comment: no.  The "magic" is in the incrementing sPtr.  putchar doesn't disolve anything.  It's not even called until the end of the string has been reached... Run it on paper.

Comment: Oh it wouldn't be called. I see that now. The only thing I still do not understand is what is incrementing sPtr. I see the function constantly sending a pointer to array element 1? How is it changing?

Comment: Vlad every time it's position 1 relative to the previous position 1.  E.g. if the original pointer was 1, the next call will be 2, the next 3 etc.  sPtr has a different value every call (it's a different variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is recursively calling itself for every successive character in the string and on reaching the `\0` character, which is the base case, is unwinding printing the characters in reverse order.

---

**Step 1** :

```
void reverse( const char * const sPtr ){ //This calls the function with string
```

Here, sPtr points to the first character of the string.

**Step 2** :

```
reverse( &sPtr[1] ); //This calls the function with the next character of the string
```

This line is what takes the function forward.

**Step 3** :

Repeat these two steps you reach the end of the string, the base case.

---

It is not reversing the string but simply printing the string in reverse.

Comment: How is it unwinding? I only see that &strPtr[1] is recursively sent. How does the third character strPtr[2] get reached?

Comment: the first time reverse is called, it has the address of sPtr[0], then you call reverse with the address of sPtr[1], so when you are in your reverse function again, sPtr[0] actually is the sPtr[1] you passed to the function before

Comment: There it is. I missed that part completely. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

suppose your string is "Viad"

first it sends "Viad" to reverse function,

```
reverse("Viad");
```

in reverse function, again you are calling to reverse function but this time you are sending address of your second character i.e. you are sending "iad" ,

```
reverse("iad");
```

again it calls to reverse, now it sending "ad",

```
reverse("ad");
```

again "d",

```
reverse("d");
```

now it sends '\0' end character

now this time it `return` & 
now it rewinds because of `Stack functionality`, i.e. when we calls some oher function it saves current status of variables in stack & after completing all statements from that functon it returns means it pop from stack all saved status

now it goes to statement

```
putchar('d');
```

it prints "d" &

then it prints "da" & then "dai" & then "daiV" that means it goes on rewind it